# Awesome Font appearing as Squares

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, sass, font-awesome

I have ant html page page using a CSS class to display an AwesomeFont with the content **f058**, but its appearing as a square now.

HTML :-

```
<div class="sucessfullChange">

    <div class="sucessfullUsageChangeMessageConfirmation">

    </div>
    <span style="word-break: break-all" class="sucessfullChangeMessage">Congrats.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.sucessfullUsageChangeMessageConfirmation {
    &:after {
        content: "\f058";
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: $colorGreen;
        font-size: 31px;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        left: 28px;

        @include for-tablet {
            left: 19px;
        }

        @include for-phone {
            top: 14px;
            left: 36px;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: please check is your font awesome file properly included?

Comment: see console for error,may be your font is not loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

if you forget to add the font-awesome css liberary, Plz add the link in the head tag of your HTML as

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I think it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

When icon is showing as a square it reflect that it is not linked properly.
You can either link your icons via cdn using this link [cdn icons link](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css%22%3E)

or you can choose to download icons as png images and use them to your work

http://fa2png.io/